# Update data present in database by php

Tags: php, mysql, database

Created a table "test_mysql" in database "test"
I have 3 files
1. list_records.php
2. update.php
3. update_ac.php

Databse code

Create database and table using phpMyAdmin

```
CREATE TABLE `test_mysql` (
`id` int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`name` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`lastname` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`email` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
-- 
-- Dumping data for table `test_mysql`
--
INSERT INTO `test_mysql` VALUES (1, 'Billly', 'Blueton', 'bb5@phpeasystep.com');
INSERT INTO `test_mysql` VALUES (2, 'Jame', 'Campbell', 'jame@somewhere.com');
INSERT INTO `test_mysql` VALUES (3, 'Mark', 'Jackson', 'mark@phpeasystep.com');
INSERT INTO `test_mysql` VALUES (4, 'Linda', 'Travor', 'lin65@phpeasystep.com');
INSERT INTO `test_mysql` VALUES (5, 'Joey', 'Ford', 'fordloi@somewhere.com');
INSERT INTO `test_mysql` VALUES (6, 'Sidney', 'Gibson', 'gibson@phpeasystep.com');
```

---

list_records.php

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="test_mysql"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>

<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>
<table width="400" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td colspan="4"><strong>List data from mysql </strong> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="center"><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Lastname</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Email</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Update</strong></td>
</tr>

<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $rows['name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['lastname']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['email']; ?></td>

// link to update.php and send value of id 
<td align="center"><a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>">update</a></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>

</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<?php
mysql_close();
?>
```

---

update.php

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="test_mysql"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// get value of id that sent from address bar
$id=$_GET['id'];

// Retrieve data from database 
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>

<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="update_ac.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Update data in mysql</strong> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center"><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Lastname</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Email</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="<?php echo $rows['name']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname" value="<?php echo $rows['lastname']; ?>" size="15">
</td>
<td>
<input name="email" type="text" id="email" value="<?php echo $rows['email']; ?>" size="15">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>
<input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>

<?php
// close connection 
mysql_close();
?>
```

---

update_ac.php

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="test_mysql"; // Table name 
$id='id';
$name="name";
$lastname="lastname";
$email="email";

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// update data in mysql database 
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET name='$name', lastname='$lastname', email='$email' WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully updated. 
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='list_records.php'>View result</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}

?>
```

Now the problem is after applying all this code I am still unable to update any row..PLS HELP ME OUT :( it shows updates succesfully but it doesnot update anything.

Comment: Why do you have a form if `update_ac.php` sets the variables?

Comment: Echo out that SQL query. It won't look like you're expecting. Specifically, you're passing in `$id` to the WHERE clause, but you're setting `$id='id'` at the top of update_ac.php

Answer (score 1):

I got your problem and it is here

```
$id='id';
```

Instead of giving numeric value you are giving characters which is invalid, Give proper id value to your query.

Currently your query reads like this

```
$sql="UPDATE test_mysql SET name='name', lastname='lastname', email='email' WHERE id='id'";
```

here your where clause is failing.

Comment: actually when I wont define variable over top browser shows error..Variable id is undefined thats why I define it on the top. But the problem is still the same :(

Comment: @SwatiKanojia did not exactly understood your problem. Can you explain so that we can solve

Comment: actually I need to update more than many data so I cant give id a valu say 1 or 2

Comment: actually I just dont know what to do so that It update the row data say by using id it update or change name lastname email of the given existing data in db

Comment: sir ..sorry I make u confuse but all I want is how to update my data via php to database

Comment: Basically you should get id from form and get that id using this $id = $_POST['id']; then use this id to update your db.

Comment: you mean I shud use #id = $_POST['id']; instead of $id="id"; ?

Comment: Problem is still the same :(

Answer (score 0):

update_ac.php

modify

```
$id=$_POST['id'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
```

also in update.php better to use
`$id=intval($_GET['id'])`;

Comment: Now, can u pls tell me what to do to change the uploaded image? just like we change the data

Comment: you should use `<input type="file" name="file" id="file">` in your form and $_FILES for uploading. [refer to here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) for example

Comment: Thank youuuu sir ..this is it..but one more thing pls tell me that i have a column of image in db and now with every unique id I want that different stored image to appear on webpage...can u pls suggest me the code like how to echo image like we did with name <?php echo $rows['name']; ?>

Comment: it is something like `<img src="<?php echo file_dir . '/' . $imagename; ?>...` which `file_dir` is folder for keeping uploaded files and `$imagename` is image file name you stored at your table.

Comment: Sir I need to deifine something on the top also? say SELECT from... or directly use this <img src="<?php echo file_dir . '/' . $imagename; ?>

Comment: actually it is `$rows['your-image-column-name']` and not simply $imagename. so you need to, just like for `$rows['name']`

Comment: Yes sir this is what m asking my image column name is 'image' so shud i write : <?php echo $rows['image']; ?> like i did for name but this shows images/avtar.jpg ...not displaying image

Comment: leave it sir its done :) Thanks for giving me your precious time sir..Its my pleasure learning from u :)